# How to use pure JavaScript to determine whether Facebook/Twitter is blocked?

Tags: javascript

Some countries like China is blocking Facebook/Twitter. How to use JavaScript to check whether a website is not accessible?

update:

I am adding a "Share to Facebook" button on a web page. 50% of the visitors are from China and 50% are from outside of China.

For those China visitors, they would never see that Facebook button because it's blocked. I want to use `$.hide()` or `$.empty()` to remove the related HTML if I detected that Facebook is blocked. How can I do that?

Comment: Try and get a page you know exists?  :P

Comment: small image might be easier; set up an onload handler, if it doesn't fire in a short time, site's probably not accessible (works until they remove that image).

Comment: You probably could check if there js web api is also blocked in china, if yes you can figure this out by trying to load the api and if it fails, then it is most probably blocked, or a timeout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if URL is accessible from web browser i.e. make sure not blocked by Proxy server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621697/test-if-url-is-accessible-from-web-browser-i-e-make-sure-not-blocked-by-proxy-s)

Answer (score 3):

You can check if loading the facebook SDK is blocked in china (`//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js`)

If this is the case then you could do something like this:

```
  $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js')
  .success(function(){
        // do something if facebook is available 
  });
```

You need to take care because you need to define a timeout if you want to make a callback for the `fail` case. I need to check the correct settings later, but currently i don't have time to.

**EDIT**

Based on the comment of `funkybro` it would be better to do a JSONP request. Loading the API would inject a butch of code you probably don't need.
So just request e.g.:

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/feed?callback=?')
.success(function(){
     // do something if facebook is available 
});
```

The request will include a failure code because you don't provide at *graph node*, but knowing that you get an error message from facebook means that it is reachable for the client.

Comment: yep JSONP is the way to go

Comment: @funkybro yes JSONP this a better choice then loading the api because it would not inject facebook code to the page, at least if they only reply with a script that is just calling the jsonp callback what they hopefully do :D .

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) like this:

```
$.get("http://facebook.com").fail(function() {
    $(...).hide()
}).done(function() {
    $(...).show()
})
```

Note that this is a cross-site request that will fail for security reasons unless you disable that browser feature.

If that's not possible for you, I suggest you use GeoIP or similar technologies to determine the users origin.

Comment: This will always fail, because it results in an `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`  error.

Comment: It will fail unless you start the browser with that feature turned off. With purse JS, this is the only way I can think of to solve it.

Comment: Sure but it is for visitors, I don't think it is a good solution to tell all visitors to turn of the security feature.

Comment: @t.niese I agree. I added a note to this post briefly describing the problem.