# Detecting blocked local URLs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm putting in a link to a local network URL inside a website i.e.

```
<a href="file://///server/share">Your network share</a>
```

in an application, and I'm aware of the [potential for browsers to block the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465010/html-links-to-local-network-shares).

I was wondering if there's any way to either detect or predict the blocking so I can show an alternative result to the user (Like just telling them the path instead of trying to open it for them)?

Comment: this might work for you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621697/test-if-url-is-accessible-from-web-browser-i-e-make-sure-not-blocked-by-proxy-s

Comment: actually I think I found a better solution for you.. can u use jquery?

Comment: Yes, I'm already using jQuery. Any jQuery solution would work fine. The image solution though doesn't really work because the folder won't necessarily contain images & security for inline referencing local data is quite different to linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you could use a hidden iframe:

In your case I would have a click event handler on that link like so:

**EDITED**: Now using a Timeout technique to check if the frame has loaded

```
var _errtimer, link, href;
function clickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    link = $(this);
    href = link.attr('href');
    var frame = $("<iframe id='testframe' style='visibility:hidden;' src='" + href + "'></iframe>");
    $("body").append(frame);

    _errtimer = setTimeout(frameError, 2000);

    $("#testFrame").on('load', function () {
        clearTimeout(_errtimer);
        console.log('frame loaded successfuly');
        location.href = href;
    });
}
function frameError() {
    alert('error in frame');
    // no access, provide the path..
    lnk.html("the path: " + href);
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Fails on IE even when permitted (It considers it a cross-domain iframe - file://///server is another domain), passes on FireFox even when blocked (Because it doesn't even try to load it - it loads about:blank & it's happy to provide that empty HTML string back).

Comment: do you have a link where i could see it?

Comment: basically the idea is to first try and load the link in an iframe.. the function that checks to see if it's valid can be changed to fit every cross browser condition of the unwanted/wanted result in the iframe and than take action according to it

Comment: I tried a different approach that might be more helpful.. see updated answer.

Comment: Don't have a URL for it, and jsFiddle is not loading to make one right now. But the total HTML of my test page is adding `<html><body></body></html>` around the link, then sticking in your JavaScript plus a `$('a').click(clickHandler);` call.

Your approach works for testing another website URL, it does not work for a local network `file://///` protocol URL.

Comment: Ok, with the new code it fails in all browsers instead... http://jsfiddle.net/qVC6W/1/. Tested in firefox - fails incredibly slowly, tested in IE - also fails incredibly slowly even though the link below without the JS opens fine.